# Partition one AVL in two AVL trees, one containing lower than K elements, rest in other

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-search-tree, avl-tree, partition

I'm looking for some help about partitioning (splitting) one AVL tree in two AVL trees such that one contains keys lower than KEY and other contains those bigger. Those two trees that comes from it must be AVL (so height must be perfectly balanced)

My idea:

```
1. If KEY is inside tree T, find it. If not - insert it. 
   NODE_K is pointer to node with KEY.

2. Using rotations lift up NODE_K up to the root 
   cleaning after myself so that both subtrees of NODE_K are AVL.

3. Once NODE_K reaches root, in left subtree there is a TREE 
   with all smaller nodes that is stil AVL, and same thing is in right subtree, 
   only elements are bigger.
```

Time is O(log n) which is the height of the tree (since we just lift node up, and use constant rotations to restore balance in subtrees each time).

My concern is that i'm not sure, if it leaves subtrees balanced in good way and problems with different height are just keep coming bigger and bigger and bigger and once we come to the root it might be bigger than just height difference <= 1.

If u have any other ideas about that problem i'm open to suggestions, but i'd prefer to first check my "algorithm" if its even ok.

Comment: One potential problem I can see is rotating the key to the root, unless you export the initial AVL tree to a new BST and make the rotations there. Otherwise, how will you keep the tree from re-balancing itself and moving your key away from the root? Perhaps the method that moves the key to the root could also perform the rotations and the splitting of the tree, but that will be a very large method.

Comment: A second question is how are you saving your data? In an array, or in nodes with pointers to each other? If you do end up copying the AVL to a BST to perform the splitting, it seems to me the copying would go much quicker for an array than a linked list.

Comment: @JonathanLandrum i dont have to copy the tree i take, becouse i dont intend to keep it. It destroys original tree, so from one tree we take two and you dont have anymore the one you had at the start. And thats fine for me, i know i'd have to make copy if i would like to have it again.

Also i keep it as Nodes with pointers to each other, but i since i dont need to have original tree later, i dont have to copy it anywhere.

Comment: My intuition says that its better to split the problem into two smaller problems: first you find where the K would have been inserted (no need to actually insert it) and split the tree there. One tree will be a regular AVL tree and the other will be an AVL tree with one node breaking the AVL invariant. Then you figure out a way to use rotations to fix the broken tree so its fully AVL again.

Comment: @hugomg but if Key would be in leaf, then there wouldn't be any subtrees and still everything to split would be above the tree. So it wouldnt help me at all in this situation. :/